# Is existential instantiation related to "Let x be ..."

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, soft-question

I have a question about existential instantiation.

So, I am familiar with statements like "Let $x$ be an integer" or "Let $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$". These statements define $x$ to represent a particular, but arbitrarily chosen integer.

My question is, are we doing a similar thing when we do existential instantion? For example, lets start with the existential statement $P$ = "There exists an integer $x$ such that $x^2 = 4$". When we do existential instantiation on $P$, are we saying "Let $a$ be an element of the set of integers that make $P$ true?"

Comment: "Let $x$ be an integer" and "let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$" are often examples of universal instantiation, not existential. Suppose you're trying to prove a universal statement about integers: "for all integers $x, A(x)$"; here, ""Let $x$ be an integer" is a bit like "Pick an integer, any integer, and I will show you that $A(x)$".  However, as you note, sometimes these phrases are examples of existential instantiation. With your statement $P(x) \equiv x^2 = 4$, knowing that there exists an x such that $P(x)$, you can then say, "let $x_0$ be an such an $x$" — that is, such that $P(x_0)$.

Comment: So is existential instantiation for the existential statement "there exists an integer x such that P(x)", where "P(x) = x^2 = 4" is essentially "let x ∈ Z such that P(x)" ?

Comment: How is this any different than you previous question?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053156/how-to-interpret-let-in-mathematics

Comment: @fleablood I'm asking about existential instantiation in this case. So, let's say we know that "there exists an integer x such that P(x)", where "P(x) = x^2 = 4" is true. Then, when we do existential instantion, aren't we just saying "let x ∈ Z such that P(x)"? If we didn't know the truth value of the existential claim, we wouldn't be able to say "let x ∈ Z such that P(x)".

Comment: I was just scouring the web, and I found this paper helpful: https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter12.pdf

Comment: I already told you earlier, you should read [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550). If you don't understand actual logical reasoning, you simply cannot understand how wrong those answers you have gotten earlier are.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you already have a theorem $\exists x.P(x)$ then you can apply existential instantiation to derive $P(a)$, where $a$ is a new symbol. If you don't have the existence theorem, though, then introducing $P(a)$ constitutes making a new assumption that you need to keep track of.

In normal natural-language math exposition, we don't always clearly distinguish between these two situations at the point where $P(a)$ is introduced - the formal proof structure is something the reader reconstructs based on their understanding of what's being explained.