# Let $b\in \mathbb R$. There exists $a\in \mathbb N$ such that $b < a < b+1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

This seems like it is true since b is a real number it can be 10.5 for example, and a is 11.

I am thinking it could be false since it doesn't hold for every number? Like if b is 10.5, let a be 18. Do inequalities like this have to hold ALWAYS for them to be considered true regardless of the numbers assigned to the variables? I've searched around but can't find a clear answer on that, apologies if it is obvious. The phrasing of the question throws me off because it just says 'There exists.'

Comment: This is false if $b$ is an integer, say $b = 1$.  Are you missing an "$\leq$" in "$b < a < b+1$"?

Comment: In particular it is false, if $b+1$ is negative , since $a$ as a natural number can then not be smaller.

Comment: Assuming the statement is $b\leq a<b+1$ with $a\in\mathbb Z$, let $S\subset\mathbb Z$ be the set of integers less than $b$. $b$ is an upper bound, so there must be a least upper bound. It's easy to see that this least upper bound must be an integer. Call it $a-1$. Can you show that $a$ has the properties you claim?

Comment: You don't let $a=18$, rather you find an $a$ which works ("there exists" means you can find at least one such $a$, and does not mean that every value of $a$ must work).

Comment: I am not missing a ≤. the question is exactly as I submitted. b < a < b+1

Comment: @MathPoser22 Then it is false, with the counterexample Eric provided.

Comment: @DonThousand That's what is confusing me a little Don. The question says, 'There exists.' Does that not indicate there only has to be 1 example of it being true for it to be true? A single counterexample would only be sufficient if the question is 'for all' ?

Comment: @MathPoser22 No, we need one $a$ for EVERY real number $b$.

Comment: Otherwise unquantified variables, $b$ in the sentence you are focussing on, are universally quantified.  So, as a single sentence, "For all $b \in \Bbb{R}$, there exists an $a \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $b < a < b+1$."  So, for each and every choice of $b$, there must be at least one $a$ making the inequality true.  Is there a $b$ for which that $a$ does not exist?

Comment: @EricTowers and Peter, thank you. That clears it up for me. I appreciate the help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we write “Let $b\in \mathbb R$” in a proof to declare the variable $b$ as an *arbitrary*/dummy real number; because $b$ is just a placeholder for a general but no particular member of $\mathbb R,$ whatever ensuing derivation involving it generally applies to *any* real number in its place; we can then conclude by writing “For each $b\in \mathbb R,$ [the derived result involving $b$]”. See: [How to interpret "let" in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4053215/21813)

> Let $b\in \mathbb R$. There exists $a\in \mathbb N$ such that $b < a < b+1$.

Guided by the above context where we convert “let $b\in \mathbb R$” (“let $b$ be an arbitrary real number”) to “for each $b\in \mathbb R$”, then the given two-sentence claim is false: $b=10$ is a counterexample.

On other hand, if we are intended to understand the given claim as true, then we can conclude that $b\in\mathbb R^+{\setminus}\mathbb Z.$