# Prove $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove using definition of a limit that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2} = 0$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Note that $\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right| \leq \frac 1 {x^2}$ for $x\ne 0$. Then choose $M= \frac 1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Then if $x> M$ implies that $\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right| \leq \frac 1 {x^2} < \epsilon$.

Am I allowed to give an $M$ the way I did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Your proof is correct. That's how one chooses $M$. Though "Let we have for $x>M$" looks strange for me. The writing can be slightly modified as:

> Let $\epsilon>0$. Note that $\displaystyle |\frac{\sin x}{x^2}|\le \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x\ne 0$. Let $M=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Then for $x>M$, one has
> $$
> |\frac{\sin x}{x^2}|\le\frac{1}{x^2}<\epsilon\;.
> $$
> Q.E.D.

Comment: Yes, typo. Thanks!

Comment: @user10101 If the issue has been resolved, [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers#comment12870_3400) and/or upvoting answers is the best way to say "thanks!": it scores points, signals resolution, and prevents bumping and automatic deletion.  Two small suggestions for further editing: 1) delete "for"; 2) change the second "let" to "choose/put".

Comment: @ryang, yes. Was planning to accept answer. I am not new to this. There is a 5 min window before accepting…

Comment: @ryang I believe “let” is fine as I see many people use this vernacular in their proofs. “for” is a condition statement, thus, is necessary.

Comment: @user10101 (1) "[let](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4053215/21813)" is fine; I suggested to replace the *second* one only to distinguish the "forall" variable from the "exists" variable; it's not important and I did say it's just a small suggestion . (2) No, the construction "*if/for* [condition] **implies that** [consequent]" is ungrammatical; if you insist on the "if/for", then delete "implies that" (optionally, replace "implies that" with "then / one has / we have", like what this Answer does).

Comment: @user10101: *ryang* is wrong. The "Let ε>0." is common but very bad; see [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550).

Comment: "Let ε>0", in this context, is short for ""Let ε be an *arbitrary* positive number", and is absolutely standard and correct. The word "let" here is merely declaring a variable, while the unstated word "arbitrary" is performing [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation); when [wrapping up the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4500910/21813), it is _because_ ε had been arbitrary that we can then conclude, "for each ε...".