# Difference between “for some $k$” and “for some arbitrary $k$”

Tags: analysis, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am told that the “for some” and “for some arbitrary”  are different.

For example, when proving the statement “if n is odd, then $n^2$ is odd”, one of the steps includes writing $$\text{$n = 2k+1,\:\:$ where $k$ is some integer}.$$ I am told that writing “$k$ is some arbitrary integer” here is wrong?

On the other hand, in mathematical induction, when performing the inductive step, before writing the inductive hypothesis for $k,$ we write “for some arbitrary $k\text”$. I am then told that the “arbitrary” here is compulsory to write.

To me, they sound the same. Am I wrong? Are they different in terms of notation?

PS I’m relatively new to this stuff, maybe explain less using notation and appeal more to logical understanding.

Comment: Essentially, "$P$ is true for arbitrary $k$" means that it's true for all $k$. "$P$ is true for some $k$" means that there exists a $k$ for which it's true. For example, for a given $n$, it's certainly not true that $n = 2k+1$ for *all* $k$; there simply exists a $k$ for which it *is* true. However, if we write "$k^2$ for arbitrary $k$ can be written as the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers," that's true for all (positive) $k$.

Comment: Writing "for some arbitrary k" is fine both cases you described.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your first example, I would just write “where $k$ is an integer”. But “some” is okay. The point is, since $n$ is already known, $k$ is completely determined. Writing “where $k$ is some arbitrary integer” implies, or at least suggests, that $k$ can be *any* integer.

In an inductive proof on the other hand, we do mean that $k$ can be any positive integer. Writing “for some arbitrary positive integer $k$, $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$” means the same as “for all positive integers $k$, $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$.”

Comment: This comment isn't a full answer, especially since OP prefers a notation-light response: but it might be worth noting that this is essentially the difference between the formal notations ∃ (the first case: this is true for “some” $k$) and ∀ (the second case: this is true for “all”, or for “arbitrary” $k$).

Comment: Agree. In the first example, I would say $n$ is an arbitrary odd integer. But $k$ depends on $n$ so it's not arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

In proofs like those you're describing, the purpose of singling out "some $k$" having "such and such property" is to prove something about all other numbers having the same property of $k$. For this reason, you can describe $k$ as arbitrary, although it is not strictly necessary. I have seen both covnentions used. What people typically mean by "for some $k$" or "for some arbitrary $k$" is "*here is a particular number $k$ that is not uniquely different from any other number having the same properties.*"

Comment: I actually haven’t seen the two phrases used synonymously. Aant’s comment succinctly explains the difference in my experience.

Comment: i believe you are both incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> when proving the statement “if n is odd, then $n^2$ is
> odd”, one of the steps includes writing $$\text{$n = 2k+1,\:\:$ where $k$ is some integer}.$$ I am told that writing “$\boldsymbol k$ **is some arbitrary integer**” here is wrong?

The full statement, written without ambiguity, is:

- Given **an arbitrary odd integer**  $\boldsymbol n,$ there is **some integer** $\boldsymbol k$ such that $n = 2k+1.$

  (That is, $\;\forall n{\in}\{\text{odd integers}\}\:\:\exists k{\in}\mathbb Z\:\:n = 2k+1.)$

Once we have arbitrarily taken an odd integer $n$ (in other words, once we have taken *any* odd integer $n$), only a *particular* integer $k$ satisfies the given equation. Since $k$ depends on the choice of $n,\;k$ is certainly not arbitrary.

> I am told that the “for some” and “for some arbitrary” are different.

The former means existential quantification $(∃),$ whereas the latter means universal quantification $(∀).$ To avert any potential for confusion, it is better to rewrite the latter as “for *an* arbitrary” or “given *an* arbitrary” or “for each”.

> On the other hand, in mathematical induction, when performing the
> inductive step, before writing the inductive hypothesis for $k,$ we
> write “for some arbitrary $k\text”$. I am then told that the
> “arbitrary” here is compulsory to write.

When indicating universal quantification, [the word “arbitrary” is actually frequently tacit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4053215/21813); “take an integer”  is typically understood to mean “take an arbitrary integer” (“for each integer”), which of course does not mean “for some integer”.